# Is there a framework to manage iPhone home page icons?

Tags: cocoa, frameworks

Is there a framework, or are there some good tutorials that can help me to work with the home icons in iOS?  I need to make an app that can group all the applications I have made.

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't allow developers any access to the home screen, icons, icon positions or anything like that.  Unless you're talking about on a jailbroken device, there is no way to do what you're asking.